# Why am I getting "sequence size must match size of the row" error?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I'm trying to use an Insert Cursor to insert a point geometry into an existing point feature class.

I'm finding the coordinate and appending them to a list called rowValues, ex:

```
rowValues.append("((({0}, {1}), 34))".format(X, Y))
```

This is giving me a list of value in this format:

```
((3656320.51246, 1613747.99484), 34)
```

Here is the cursor I am using:

```
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("Points",("SHAPE@XY","QuarterSections"))
```

When I run this code:

```
for row in cursor:
    cursor.insertRow(row)
```

I get this follow error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Quarter.py", line 110, in <module>
    cursor.insertRow(row)
TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row
```

Can I not use the string formatting? I've been trying to figure this out for awhile now, but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cursor is expecting a tuple, not a string. You might be able to convert the string to a tuple after the fact using [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3946174/386205). However, it would be far better practice to produce the tuple without using a string as an intermediary.

The better way to do this would be to change:

```
"((({0}, {1}), 34))".format(X, Y)
```

To:

```
((X, Y), 34)
```

Is there a particular reason you are using a string?

Comment: No, you're definitely right. I'm not sure why I was doing it that way. I got it to work.